# Is it possible to avoid huge number of access tokens in database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I've built a RESTful API with a Laravel Passport project.
It's using the Client Credentials Grant to authorize my third party project.
The problem is that for each api call from the third party application it generates a new access token.
By the end of the day, if i had 999 calls i will have also 999 new records in the oauth_access_tokens database table.
It's possible to avoid huge number of access tokens in database?

Maybe in League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\ClientCredentialsGrant.php:

```
public function respondToAccessTokenRequest(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseTypeInterface $responseType, \DateInterval $accessTokenTTL) {
    $client = $this->validateClient($request);
    $scopes = $this->validateScopes($this->getRequestParameter('scope', $request));
    $scopes = $this->scopeRepository->finalizeScopes($scopes, $this->getIdentifier(), $client);
    // $validToken = query to check if $client has existing token neither revoked or expired
    // if ($validToken) { 
    //     return $responseType->setAccessToken($validToken);
    // }
    $accessToken = $this->issueAccessToken($accessTokenTTL, $client, null, $scopes);
    $responseType->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    return $responseType;
}
```

Comment: Sure, store and reuse the same access token?

Comment: @ceejayoz, are you suggesting storing the access token in the third party application? It seems to me that is not a good practise or, even impossible if the third party code is not developed by me.

Comment: Yes, it would be typical for a third-party application to store a token for a period of time. The Facebook app on my phone, for example, stores a token for up to 60 days.

Comment: you can delete old token before generating the new one.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you very much for your point of view. However i'm still not comfortable with letting to the third party developer the responsibility of not letting my database growing unnecessary .

Comment: @Webinion, I'm trying to figure out how can i do that, i'm looking to Laravel/Passport and League/oauth2-server but i'm getting lost. Following Route::post(oauth/tokens) i'm directed to Laravel/Passport/Http/Controllers/AccessTokenController@issueToken and this method calls the oauth2 server method respondToAccessTokenRequest, then i got lost...

Comment: yeah you can store and reuse it until he gets logout from your platform when he does you can delete that token from DB

Comment: Sorry @Mr.Pyramid, it's a client credentials grant (without users, only client applications).

Comment: set token lifetime in the auth config file. and use client tokens for each app.

Comment: @Amin, I think that will not reduce the number of records in the database, maybe it will reduce the number of active tokens.

Comment: In theory I like @Webinion solution but I don't know where, when and how to do it. Personally I would prefer a solution like: if client->token is active then return token else issueNewToken and return token, in this case only if token was inactive then a new record was going to be created, but, again i'm not seen where and how to do that

Comment: @RicardoCarvalho, can you add code in question itself with formatting so its readable.

Comment: Sorry @Webinion that wasn't code, it's me thinking loud. I dont even know if it exists a client object

Comment: You're finding something native or some solution. In both cases I think you're in luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution**
Set a listener to the event generated by Passport when a access token is created.

app/Providers/eventServiceProvider.php:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    protected $listen = [
        'Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated' => [
            'App\Listeners\RevokeOldTokens'
        ]
    ];
    public function boot() {
        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

app/Listeners/RevokeOldTokens.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated;
use Laravel\Passport\Client;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class RevokeOldTokens {
    public function __construct() {
        //
    }
    public function handle(AccessTokenCreated $event) {
        $client = Client::find($event->clientId);
        // delete this client tokens created before one day ago:
        $client->tokens()->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDay())->forceDelete();
    }
}
```

Comment: ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#events and https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/7.0/src/Events/AccessTokenCreated.php#L36-L41

Comment: `->forcedelete()` should be `->forceDelete()`